# Getting response data from Alamofire error

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I've been using Alamofire in one of my iOS projects, but recently when upgrading to Alamofire 3.0 the format changed slightly for returning results. In my case I want to call a login API and have it return the result. There are a couple errors that could happen, so I always return in the API result what the problem is, so I would like my code to go into a failure block if the response is a 400 and then include the message from my API as part of the error, but I can not seem so get the response data from the request when the result is a failure.

Here's my code:

```
Alamofire.request(
        method,
        Constants.baseURL + route,
        parameters: fullParameters)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                completion?(json["data"])
            case .Failure(let errorData):
                failure?(errorData, json["errmsg"])
            }
    }
```

What is happening in this, is that when the response is a failure, it breaks because response.result.value is nil, but I would like it to be the JSON returned from the API no matter what. When the response is a success on the other hand it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're calling `validate()` Alamofire is automatically validating status code from `200...299`.

If you don't want Alamofire to validate your status code, but you want to do it yourself manually you have two options:

- Remove `.validate()` and handle everything manually.
- Change `validate()` to `.validate(statusCode: yourRange)` for the range you want to allow and handle them manually.

More info [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#validation).